# How can I view the state of and control a python script running regularly on a server?

Tags: monitoring

I have a python scraper on a server which runs a few times per day and also writes some logs. What's the best and easiest way to know what's going at any given time: is it running, everything working well, any problem, etc.?

Should I

- create a web GUI interface?
- write some information into the database to be able to easily access and represent it on a web GUI?

  Parsing the logs without any particular structure is difficult.

Note that I don't want to use a third-party web service to archive this goal; I want my custom and simple solution.

Comment: you said that it write some logs, so you can know from logs !!!
increase the log level if you want more info !!!!

Comment: Your question is too broad and asks for opinion (_What's the best and easiest way to..._). This is not how StackExchange works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a web server, you can maybe create a simple html that it contains the script's log. You can use the same name each time that the script creates the html, so you can overwrite it. That way each time you go to your web page which contains the log, you know that its' the latest. In case you want the full log, you can also append to the same html file the latest logs and you can have a full "log report".